# MySQL is not using new data

Tags: mysql, mariadb, scheduler

The MariaDB / MySQL event scheduler does not use new data. It only works on data that was in the table at the time of creating the event. How do I make it use whatever is in the table at the time?

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS my_calculation
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND STARTS '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
DO
SET @c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table);
SET @rownum = 0;
UPDATE my_table
SET rank = (100 / @c) * (@rownum:= 1 + @rownum)
ORDER BY another_column DESC LIMIT 100000;
```

Answer (score 1):

its because in your event query you have this line :

```
ORDER BY progress DESC LIMIT 100000;
```

So it always process only 100000 first rows that are ordered by progress column , remove `LIMIT 100000` and you will be fine.

Comment: I don't understand. Plus without the order then the calculation won't work properly. I need the order to calculate rownum

Comment: but you are limiting to  100000 rows only , remove "LIMIT 100000"

Comment: but then wont it default to 1000? That's not enough for me

Comment: no , when you don't mention limit , it will be done for all the rows in table/

Comment: I don't understand why limit stops it from using new data. Right now I only have 6 rows

Comment: hmmm... then I don't understand the problem . you have to provide more information , tell us what you mean by it doean't use new data

Comment: I removed limit and it still doesn't work. When I drop the event and then create it again, the rank is calculated incorrectly. I think rownum isn't going back to 0

Comment: I mean I create the event to put data in a field within a row. It does it on all existing rows. But then if I add a new row, and then wait 5 seconds, refresh the table, still no calculation was performed on the new row.

Comment: hmmm... when you run "SHOW PROCESSLIST;" do you see any process with "event_scheduler"  username running?

Comment: I see 6 with user root and 1 with user event_scheduler

Comment: 5 of those root ones have the command sleep

Comment: its actually the `@c = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table);` that is causing the rank calculation error. I don't know how to make it select the current number of rows (including the newly added one)

Comment: Do you think I'm better off using postgreSQL? I seem to be getting a lot of these sort of errors that make no sense to me. I haven't used postgreSQL but maybe it's a bit more logical?